# how to get permission to access the index.html file that comes with apache on raspberry pi

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

for a while now I have been attempting to edit the index.html file that is created when you install apache2 / php5 / liapache2 ect. The command I used to install it was: 
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5

But whenever I try to save my edited version of the index.html, file it comes up with access denied. Furthermore if I try to edit it in nano nothing comes up
these are the commands I used :

cd /var/www/
sudo nano index.html

Any suggestions?
it would mean a lot to me if someone answered this question
Thanks

Comment: Is the filesystem rw?

Comment: no not that i know of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it says in the Apache documentation from raspberrypi.org:

> By default the html directory and index.html file are both owned by the root user. [Setting up an Apache web server on a Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md)

What worked for me is that I changed the owner from root to pi for /www/ and /html/ with this commands:

```
sudo chown pi: .
sudo chown pi: ..
```

But note that I'm also just using the Apache server for an local installation and I don't care about security at this point. I don't know how secure this solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions of the entire folder

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/html
```